Transformation of the fundamental domain of $PSL_2(Z)$ by the matrix $S$
Let $S=\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right).$ The transformation (Mobius) of  the fundamental domain of $PSL_2(Z)$ by the matrix $S$ is a cusp under the previous region. The elements of the fundamental domain of $PSL_2(Z)$ are mapped to $Sz=-1/z$. My doubt is how to visualize that region. I know the picture, but why does the region look like that? I don't see it.


It looks this way because we identify points by applying $T$ or $S$, or its inverses. So we obviously can always identify a point with one in the shaded region. Try an example point, and apply these transformations to the point. Remember, $T(z)=z+1$ and $S(z)=-1/z$.

Yes, I understood that. I also can visualize the regions $T,T^2,T^{-1},$ etc. But I can not see why $S$ is of that form, that cusp to down.

For this, there is a beautiful realisation, where you can use your mouse. See here.

@DietrichBurde It is indeed beautiful! And do you know any source that contains an algebraic explanation?

Yes, indeed. I recommend this book.

One way is to first show that any mobius transformation takes circle/lines to circle/lines (i.e. the image of a line or a circle is a line or a circle, but it is possible for a circle to map to a line or for a line to map to a circle).
The $S$ transformation is $Sz = -1/z$. The point $z = \infty$ is mapped to $0$. The point $\rho$ is mapped to $1 + \rho = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$. Choose any other point on the vertical line through $\rho$, like say $\tau = -1/2 + 5i$. Then $S\tau = -1/(-1/2 + 5i) \approx 0.0198 + 0.198i$, just barely above and to the right of $0$. Then the vertical line through $\rho$ maps to the circle through the points $0$, $\approx 0.0198 + 0.198i$, and $1 + \rho$.
A similar computation shows that the vertical line through $1 + \rho$ maps to the bottom left bounding circle for the image labelled $S$ on your graph. And as $S\rho = 1 + \rho$, $S(1 + \rho) = \rho$ and $Si = i$, the top bounding circle of the region labelled $S$ is fixed by $S$.
(I suppose in principle you could worry that $S$ maps the inside of the typical fundamental domain to the outside of the region labelled $S$. If you're worried about this, you can also compute that $S(2i) = i/2$, so that in fact its mapped to the interior).
